# Which is best dataset for sorting and removing duplicated in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, hashset, duplicates, treeset

If used

> TreeSet

, it provides no guarantee of removing duplicates because of its binary search method.

If used

> HashSet

, it provides no sorting.

I want both functionality together in a dataset. Which is preferable ways for the same ?

**Is it that the only way is to remove duplicates first using HashSet & then copy it to TreeSet for sorting ?**

Comment: write a comparator for your hashset , what the prob ??

Comment: `TreeSet` should work fine, if your `compareTo()` is consistent with `equals()`.

Comment: @kiheru: Not working. As equals() methods of TreeSet is not used runtime.

Comment: TreeSet *does* have guarantees of removing (or not adding) duplicates because it is still a *Set*. See the documentation for additional contracts it requires (namely that the elements are well-ordered by compareTo).

Comment: That's why I mentioned the consistency requirement. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): *Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface.*

Answer (score 2):

Use `TreeSet` and if `compareTo()` returns 0 for two elements than it will be replaced, hence only unique elements will be present..

```
 TreeSet<Object1> tree=new TreeSet<Object1>(new Comparator<Object1>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object1 o1, Object1 o2) {
            return o1.k-o2.k;
        }
    });
```

Here `Object1` is like below:

```
class Object1{
    int k;
}
```

If the two Objects of `Object1` are same i.e. `int k` than the `compare()` method will return 0 and `TreeSet` will detect the duplicate. Hope i am clear.

Comment: It won't work for many objects because TreeSet won't compare each & every Object but only near by objects will be compared.

Comment: @Sarang Then a *broken compareTo is used*. This is no different than a HashSet not working of a *broken hashCode is used*.

Comment: It looks like he thinks that you can't trust piece-wise equality comparison (even if it's implemented in a fashion that guarantees global uniqueness, **and even if it says so in the docs**).

Comment: @Sarang, I do not knew TreeSet doesn't work for many objects(on uniqness), Do you have any scenario to explain that, may useful for people

Comment: @Sarang it is not like you think, please see my example and if you have any specific doubt please ask.